# How are you meant to salvage fuses in Cutter's R.A.C.E.?

Tags: hardspace-shipbreaker

In today's Cutter's R.A.C.E., one of the objectives is to salvage two fuses. However, I can't figure out where I'm meant to put them. Putting them in the barge doesn't count, throwing one in a furnace or the processor fails the objective, and I'm not getting an option to pick them up as the destination tooltip suggests. Is this objective simply not possible due to a bug, or am I missing something?

[image: A fuse marked with salvage destination "pickup" without any option to pick it up]